# Laravel 5 controller sending JSON integer as string

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, php-5.6

On my development server the JSON response from the Laravel 5 controller shows the data in the correct types.

e.g

```
imdb_rating: 7.6
imdb_votes: 6271
```

But on the production server, the JSON response is sent back as strings.

```
imdb_rating: "7.60"
imdb_votes: "6271"
```

Both development and production have the same version of PHP installed (5.6.11-1).

Any ideas on what may be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Is the data coming from mysql table?

Comment: May sound stupid, but can you check if you are using *MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd)* on both machines? *MySQL Client Library* driver returning all fields as strings regardless of type, which is not the case when using *MySQL Native Driver*

Comment: Well, with PHP version 5.6 you probably do.

Comment: Did you try `return response()->json(["foo" => "bar"], 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` ?

Comment: @DavidDomain you're right- the production system was not using the native driver!

Comment: @DavidDomain could you post it as an answer.

Comment: I have added an answer.  Might be good for other who come across this.

Comment: Be careful when using the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag. If you have strings like "004004004" in your database (a phone number for example), the json response will parse it as "4004004"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Make sure to use [**MySQL Native Driver**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) which will support native data types.

> It is possible to convert integer and float columns back to PHP numbers by setting the MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE connection option, if using the mysqlnd library. If set, the mysqlnd library will check the result set meta data column types and convert numeric SQL columns to PHP numbers, if the PHP data type value range allows for it. This way, for example, SQL INT columns are returned as integers.

MySQL Client Library will return all fields as strings.

Another solution would be to use json_encode options with `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`.

For example:

```
return response()->json(["foo" => "bar"], 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: this finally solve my problem, the installation process is quite simple in ubuntu:
`apt-get remove php5-mysql`,`apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`, `service apache2 restart`

Comment: Thanks.  =D. Works con CentOS via installing  php55w-mysqlnd

Answer (score 73):

I just ran into this same issue! For those of you looking for a more appropriate solution, you might want to check out the [`$casts`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) property for Eloquent models.

The accepted solution will work, but it will also convert fields that you may not want converted. I would recommend adding this to your Eloquent model:

```php
protected $casts = [ 'imdb_rating' => 'float', 'imdb_votes' => 'integer' ];
```

This will convert the values directly in your model object, so you won't need to worry about updating multiple endpoints. I hope this helps others as it did me!

Comment: Excellent solution. I like that this solves the issue regardless of underlying platform. Here's a quick link to the docs. Great stuff here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: Annoyed that laravel requires this overhead to fix the data types. How does this affect performance?

Comment: It worked! But I still don't quite understand when my DB datatype is tinyint why do I need to manually cast it to an int? Ridiculous!

Comment: This must be the accepted answer I agree. I nearly followed the accepted answer and would have regretted the mess it could have caused in my code.

Comment: Why does this not working for me and the other one is? I am casting ` 'latitude' => 'double' `, it still sends as string.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful

Answer (score 24):

Same issue happened to me too, Laravel was returning all numerical data as string after I published to a shared hosting. But everything is working fine on my localhost. So found this solution.

Goto cPanel --> Select PHP Version --> Extensions tab

then uncheck **pdo_mysql** and check **nd_pdo_mysql** extension. See following screenshot of my cPanel extensions list
[image: cPanel extensions list]

I found this solution by comparing [phpInfo](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to-create-a-phpinfo-page/) of my localhost and shared hosting server. see following 2 screenshots of phpInfo page before and after I made the change.

Before the fix
[image: Before the fix]

After the fix
[image]

Thanks for the answer by DavidDomain and it opens my eyes to find this solution

I hope my answer will help to someone.

Comment: This worked out for me! If you are using a Cpanel from GoDaddy like me, maybe you need to configure this as well. By doing it this way, you wont have to programmatically convert every float/int/boolean data.

Comment: This works me to

Comment: thanks mate, you saved me from a lot of headache and save my time. cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can return the integer with typecasting like

```
return (int)Post::find(1)->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help too in order to make it easier! I'm using laravel v9.x.

Put the function in BaseController:

```
class Controller extends BaseController {
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public static function json($json) {
        return response()->json($json, 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
```

}

Now in your model or whatever you use:

```
return self::json($all);
```