# integer is getting converted into string on server while behaving properly on local host?

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, laravel

I am doing rest API call and getting array of object. It is returning integer data type on localhost for `id` and `customer_id`.

1. While returning strings for `id` and `customer_id`

   - `[{"id":4,"name":"x","customer_id":5}]`
2. On hosted server. Why different behavior ?

   - `[{"id":"4","name":"x","customer_id":"5"}]`

Comment: You should definitely include the code that you used, which provided the unexpected result. Otherwise, we're just guessing what may or may not have caused such unexpected results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31527918/188282 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + PDO + MySQL: how do I return integer and numeric columns from MySQL as integers and numerics in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079320/php-pdo-mysql-how-do-i-return-integer-and-numeric-columns-from-mysql-as-int)