# disable mysql native driver - php-mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to disable mysql native driver. I want to in my response get only string data, I know that it is not recommended.

I used this command to remove the extension, but it doesn't work:

```
apt-get purge php-mysqlnd
```

I got message:

```
Virtual packages like 'php-mysqlnd' can't be removed
```

Comment: im guessing you would have to compile php without it, but as i say,thats just a guess. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i deployed api written in php on new server. On mobile platforms they got now int user_id,  (previously was string).

Comment: Thats surely just an issue with the data exchange, what are you using, json? Xml?

Comment: json, but i want to in all places to send string, on previous server it worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527050/laravel-5-controller-sending-json-integer-as-string