# Only string data in response - php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I would like to get only string data in ALL my responses

Goal:

```
{"user_id": "1"}
```

but i got:

```
{"user_id": 1}
```

I read about mysql native driver, but how to disable it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527050/laravel-5-controller-sending-json-integer-as-string

Comment: but how to disable the mysql native driver?

Comment: how do you get your database rows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593765/how-to-convert-array-values-from-string-to-int

Comment: I use Eloquent to get database rows

Comment: `strval()` + `array_map()` before `json_encode()`

Comment: Check the comments on the answer in the post you linked to from Alejandro Silva... It's just another lib... But what are you really trying to accomplish here? If you just want to cast the id field to a string in your json response, either use Laravel's `$casts` or create a transformer for your output.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to achieve this? Also how do you generate this response? Do you have a model somewhere?