# Boolean value in a JSON response is converted to string on production server

Tags: php, json, laravel, boolean

I have a Laravel application. In the `users` table, I have a `boolean` column called `active`:

```
$table->boolean('active')->default(false);
```

And in the front-end I normally check to see if the user is active or not like this:

Plain JS: `if(user.active){ // do stuff }`

VueJS: `v-if="user.active"`

This approach assumes that the value of `user.active` property, which of course is coming from the json response, is a non-string value: either 0 or 1. And that's what indeed I am receiving in the local machine:

[image: response in local]

Here pink colored values represent *String* values and green colored values represent *Number* values.
So, clearly, my local machine is interpreting it as a Numeric value and when the number 0 or 1 is used in a conditional expression, it is converted to boolean.

However that's not the case on my production server. The json response in the production server is converted to string which leads to unintended behavior of my application:

[image: response in production]

Notice that the value for the `active` key is not a *Number*, it is a *String* here! And since it's interpreted as a String, any non-empty string will always evaluate to `true`; hence my condition will always evaluate to `true`.

I have two questions: a) Why is this happening? b) How can I fix it?

Additional information: Both the production and local server are running same mysql version. PHP version on prod: 7.2.8 and PHP version on local: 7.2.9.

Comment: how do you return your results json to output?

Comment: What if you implicitly cast the value to integer: `(int)$value` before sending it to the client?

Comment: @smoqadam The default way. `return Model::with('user')`. I am not doing anything new.

Comment: Note for future readers: after conducting a research I think I may have found the answer to my first question. I am experiencing the issue because [my production server is not using MySQL Native Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527050/laravel-5-controller-sending-json-integer-as-string#comment51016022_31527050) and I have two solutions: a) Ask hosting provider to install mysql native driver on production machine or b) Go through every single model and add `$casts` array to each of them to explicitly convert the json response to boolean.

Comment: Getting same issue, did you get any solution ?

Comment: @MitulMarsoniya enable MySQL native driver on your server.

Comment: "any non-empty string will always evaluate to true" is not true. "0" always evaluates to false just like 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is still receiving answers, I am going to leave the actual answer to this particular problem (Type mismatch).

Enabling the [MySQL native driver for PHP](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/) on the production server, solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an Eloquent Model for your database table you may assign the `$casts` property to your model to assure the data type within the JSON response.

For example with your "users" table:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'active' => 'boolean'
    ];
}
```

[Documentation is here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are assigning the value for the active key as a numeric value `0`. But JSON interprets *boolean* only with two values `true` and `false`. Just try to assign the value to `true` and `false` instead of `0` and `1`.

For Reference please check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm

---

##### Edit From Comments

Yes, you can modify the record in the front-end in the way you need, because you will use array and objects in the front-end. But when you post the values to the server you will convert the array objects into json string, and the json string will assume 0 or 1 as number or string and will take true and false as boolean values. So you have to assign the key in the way the JSON works. Hope this method may work when sending data from client to server as well as from server to client.

This is because of the following reasons,

Most of the front end languages are interpreted, so they execute freely without compiling. But the back end languages will compile before executing. That's why we are using var to define any datatypes and js will use them in any way. But backend languages like java and .NET needs the variable type to get defined.

And in other hand JSON is not a language. Similar to XML it is used to send raw data between client and server. And it is designed in the way to work with both front end and backend. So you have to assign the values that both platforms will accept. That why you have to assign true or false instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: You can add a setattribute method in your model which will set value to true of false when you record 0 or 1 Synyax is set$camelCasedDbField$Attribute

Comment: I think it shouldn't matter how JSON interprets boolean. It should be fine with number because `0` or `1` as conditional expression will evaluate to `false` or `true` respectively. Also, mysql boolean data type `tinyint` doesn't understand `true` or `false` it only stores `0` or `1`. The question is why that same response is represented differently on two environments: Number on local, String on production.

Comment: Yes, you can modify the record in the front-end in the way you need, because you will use array and objects in the front-end. But when you post the values to the server you will convert the array objects into json string, and the json string will assume 0 or 1 as number or string and will take true and false as boolean values. So you have to assign the key in the way the JSON works. Hope this method may work when sending data from client to server as well as from server to client