# Numbers are formatted as string after scout:import Laravel

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, algolia, laravel-5.7, laravel-scout

I had to use php artisan scout:import command, while I was developing the website in my local environment and everything worked perfectly. However, once I deployed my app and used the same command using ssh I got my model imported, but with int attributes rendered as strings, f.e. 1 was formatted as "1". Because of that, I fail to use numeric_filters. I use the MySql database in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers are rendered as the string in JSON response by default.
You could either use instructions from this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527050/laravel-5-controller-sending-json-integer-as-string` or you could use casts attributes in the model so every time model is serialized it will cast respective columns as specified.

E.g. In model, you can define something like this: 
`protected $casts = [ 
    'something' => 'float'
];`

Comment: Thanks, mate, really had a hard time figuring it out. Helped me a lot.